# SAML assertion from ADFS has a null SessionNotOnOrAfter attribute value

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, adfs3.0

I am working on enabling login to IDP (ADFS 3.0 in my case) from my server(SP) and I am using spring SAML plugin for the same. I am able to make login and logout working. But I have issue with token expiry.

After authentication, I can see an ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken generated and set in the securityContext, but the ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken.getTokenExpiration() is returned as null in my case. I was under the assumption that this field will be returned from the Idp(ADFS) as part of AuthNRequest in SamlAssertion.

I further debugged the getExpirationDate method of SAMLAuthenticationProvider and verified that the statement.getSessionNotorAfter() indeed returns null.

The ADFS server and the SP server is in different domains and thus has a time difference of more than 12 hours. Do you think this is an issue?

Any configurations needed from the IDP side (ADFS) so that SP will recieve this value?

I am stuck here and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.